# PCNTL - Fork new child process on exit of current child

Tags: php, process, pcntl

I have written a code which has the following flow:

```
function parent(){
   // fork two process and call the process_callback function
}

function process_callback(){
   // poll for id
   // process data
   // ???????
}
```

Using PCNTL I am running two simultaneous process which poll and perform some action on the data. The requirement is that, when a process has processed the ID it should die and a new process should start which will again poll and process a new ID.

In the last line `??????` i can call the `process_callback()` again (recursion), but wont that increase memory in the system ? Thats why i would prefer letting this process die and creating a new process which agains calls this `process_callback`

Comment: Not really used pcntl before, but can't you use a signal dispatch on the child before it ends, and capture it with sigtimedwait in the forker function and re-fork

Comment: `In the last line ?????? i can call the process_callback() again (recursion), but wont that increase memory in the system ?` -- infinite recursion is bad, but that's what `while (1) { ... }` (or better, `while (!timeToQuit) { ... }`) is for.

Comment: @mah :) i forgot about while(!timeToQuit) ... its funny how we forget simple solutions when given an option to explore a difficult one :P .. Thanks

Comment: @lee tried that, re-forking is happening in the child process which when exists, leaves the new process parent less.

Comment: I would say that what you need here is *3* processes, the parent and 2 children that do the actual processing. The parent can just `pcntl_wait()` so it doesn't use any resources while there is nothing to do. This also means it would be much easier to implement a setting where you can up the number of worker processes if you need to.

Comment: I thought I'd done something like this before and I've found it - see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198844/waiting-for-all-pids-to-exit-in-php/10199290#10199290)